# Chrome makes images in Views smaller

Tags: views

I made Views page in table format.
2 columns. In the left - image in format 220x220 (resizing by Drupal). Right column consists from text.
When I see page from Chrome, I noticed that images in first comn are extremely small.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width:220px to the left td elements in the table.

In css:
table tr td:first-child {width: 220px;}

Comment: But why resize does not work?

Comment: @user38998 the resize happens on the server. That means that if it works in Firefox, it works in chrome. Try right clicking on the image and choose open in new tab. You will see that the image is in the correct size.

Comment: You are right. In new tab size is correct. Why is it not correct in original tab?

Comment: The HTML table is scaling down the image. You need to make the width of the column bigger to the width of the image